Files installed to AOSP system directory aren't included in the built image
I'm following the Native Android User-Space section of the Opersys embedded Android exercises here.
I've included an Android.mk in $(CROOT)/rootfs-glibc with the following contents as directed:
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := rootfs-glibc
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := ETC
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := stub
LOCAL_MODULE_PATH := $(TARGET_OUT)/glibc

LOCAL_POST_INSTALL_CMD := mkdir -p $(TARGET_OUT)/glibc; \
    cp -af $(TOPDIR)rootfs-glibc/rootfs/* $(TARGET_OUT)/glibc; \
    ln -sf /system/glibc/lib $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/lib; \
    ln -sf /system/glibc/lib $(TARGET_ROOT_OUT)/lib64

include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)

I see the files in $(CROOT)/rootfs-glibc/rootfs have been successfully copied (I'm not sure why the empty file with the same name of the module is there, but I guess AOSP build system just does it by default, since the rest of the files are just copied in with a post install command.
> ls /aosp/android-main/out/target/product/vsoc_x86_64/system/glibc 
bin  lib  linuxrc  rootfs-glibc  sbin  usr  var

However, booted into the Cuttlefish device, only the empty rootfs-glibc file appears:
vsoc_x86_64:/ # ls /system/glibc
rootfs-glibc

I extracted the system.img to check manually and the contents are identical to what's running on the virtual device. Is it an error with how/where the files are copied to, or a build system limitation?
I'm including the package in PRODUCT_PACKAGES in build/coretarget/product/base_system.mk.
EDIT:
I get this build error after an installclean, but it seems the required dirs are generated as running m again succeeds:
[ 94% 76263/80750] Install: out/target/product/emu64x/system glibc/rootfs-glibc
FAILED: out/target/product/emu64x/system/glibc/rootfs-glibc
/bin/bash -c "(rm -f out/target/product/emu64x/system/glibc/rootfs-glibc ) && (cp out/target/product/emu64x/obj/ETC/rootfs-glibc_intermediates/rootfs-glibc out/target/product/emu64x/system/glibc/rootfs-glibc) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/emu64x/system/glibc; echo  cp -af rootfs-glibc/rootfs/* out/target/product/emu64x/system/glibc; ln -sf /system/glibc/lib out/target/product/emu64x/root/lib; ln -sf /system/glibc/lib out/target/product/emu64x/root/lib64 )"
cp -af rootfs-glibc/rootfs/bin rootfs-glibc/rootfs/lib rootfs-glibc/rootfs/linuxrc rootfs-glibc/rootfs/sbin rootfs-glibc/rootfs/usr rootfs-glibc/rootfs/var out/target/product/emu64x/system/glibc
ln: cannot create symbolic link from '/system/glibc/lib' to 'out/target/product/emu64x/root/lib': No such file or directory
ln: cannot create symbolic link from '/system/glibc/lib' to 'out/target/product/emu64x/root/lib64': No such file or directory

